# osm2pgrouting --> option '--conf' cannot be specified more than once

Tags: osm2pgrouting

I'm attempting to import some OSM files using osm2pgrouting via command line on a windows 10.

When I specify the mapconfig.xml with the -c switch, I am getting the following error:

```
option '--conf' cannot be specified more than once error
```

If I attempt the same without the -c switch, I'm getting:

```
Opening configuration file: lean
Parsing configuration

Error opening lean: No such file or directory
Failed to open / parse config file lean
```

These are the steps I've taken so far:

1) Confirmed the mapconfig.xml file was installed under the PostgreSQL/9.5/share directory.

2) Uninstalled and reinstalled postgis 2.2 via the EnterpriseDB Stack Builder.

3) Placed a copy of mapconfig.xml in the same directory as the osm files.

4) Attempted to use just the file and the file path to PostgreSQL/9.5/share.

5) Confirmed the correct pgrouting files were placed under the bin and lib directories.

6) Confirmed that the Postgis and pgrouting extension were created in the DB.

The one item I've not been able to find is a config file for osm2pgrouting to change the default config directory.

If I'm correct, if you specify a file with the -c switch, the default should be ignored, which in this case, it appears that both are being called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If appears the book that I'm following has either some unreported errata or uses some old syntax.

The fix is using --clean with an argument instead of just -clean, which was conflicting with the -c switch.